# Why bother hanging a disturbing picture in your office?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-2017

In the movie *IT* (2017), Stanley Uris's dad hangs a picture of woman with her face distorted in his office.

I am wondering why his father does it

1. His father hangs it due to personal preference, if this is the case, I will be a bit disappointed as there is no depth in the story on this picture.
2. His father does not hang it, it is an illusion only visible to Stanley Uris.
3. His father does not want it hang it, Pennywise somehow manages to influence his mind to hang it.

Is it possible for Stephen King to have explained it in the original novel? Any ideas?

Comment: This picture does not exist in the original book. Stan gets scared by drowned kids at the Derry water tower.

Comment: Hmm. I think it might be number 2 with some alterations. There might be a normal portrait of a lady and Pennywise made the face look distorted to Stanley. Although I'm not absolutely sure about it.

Comment: To be fair, I don't think most of what people hang on the walls deserves to be there. If it's not known why, maybe the answer is that he happened to like it. What with art being all subjective. Some people pay more than whole neighborhoods will make in their lifetimes just to hang a picasso on the wall. I'd have no problems burning every picasso painting to the ground. To each their own

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The painting from the movie is a Hollywood version of a well known [painting by Modigliani](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=modigliani&ia=images&iax=images) in real life. Culturally, it is acceptable and common to hang well known classical art work in a professional office.

The director of the film, Andy Muschietti, was inspired by an actual [childhood fear he had](https://bloody-disgusting.com/movie/3458110/muschietti-talks-paintings-inspired-nightmarish-new-creature/).